# How can I 301 redirect a URL with variables in it (.htaccess)?

Tags: .htaccess, variables, url, redirect

I have the following URL:

```
https://www.parcelparcel.com/nl_NL/pakket-versturen-frankrijk/?page=nl_NL/populair/pakket-naar-frankrijk/
```

Which I would like to 301 redirect to:

```
https://www.parcelparcel.com/nl_NL/pakket-versturen-frankrijk/
```

---

I tried to pull this off with the following code in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/populair/pakket-naar-frankrijk/?page=nl_NL/populair/pakket-naar-frankrijk/?$ https://www.parcelparcel.com/nl_NL/pakket-versturen-frankrijk/ [R=301,L]
```

However, without results. Can anybody advice me or tell me what I'm missing. I checked if the URL is redirected in incognito.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(.*)$
RewriteRule ^nl_NL/pakket-versturen-frankrijk/?$    nl_NL/pakket-versturen-frankrijk/?page=nl_NL/populair/pakket-naar-frankrijk/ [L]
```

Fisrt line to exclude a request that has `Query String`

The second to choose a URI that starts with `nl_NL/pakket-versturen-frankrijk/` or `nl_NL/pakket-versturen-frankrijk` and redirect it internally to `nl_NL/pakket-versturen-frankrijk/?page=nl_NL/populair/pakket-naar-frankrijk/`